# Setting text overflow to visible with no scroll bars in dynamically added divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

How can I set the text overflow to visible with no scroll bars in dynamically added `<div>`s?
Based on the docs I thought this would be the default, but there’s something I don’t understand.
Adding the text to the `<div>` directly or to a child `<p>` doesn’t seem to change the output.

Here’s a demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/fcdobbs/pen/wvEwYvd?editors=0010).

And the code from the CodePen:

```js
let container = document.querySelector("#container");
let string = "HELLO WORLD!";

for (row = 0; row < 11; row++) {
  for (col = 0; col < 16; col++) {
    let tile = document.createElement("div");
    
    container.appendChild(tile);
    $(tile).addClass("tile");
    
    if (row == 5 && col > 1 && col < 14) {
      let p = document.createElement("p");
      
      tile.appendChild(p);
      $(p).addClass("letter");
      $(p).text(string[col - 2]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  --tileWidth: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth);
}

.tile {
  display: block;
  width: var(--tileWidth);
  height: var(--tileWidth);
  position: relative;
  background-color: teal;
  font-size: calc(var(--tileWidth)*2);
  color: tomato;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Impact;
}

.letter {
  overflow: visible visible;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: It is overflowing, but then your overwriting it with the row below..

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the tile to the right & below are overwriting because they have a background color.

What you could do is either alter the order you insert the divs, eg. in reverse.  Or change the z-Index so that tiles up & left have a higher z-index.

Below is an example of altering the z-index.

```js
let container = document.querySelector("#container");
let string = "HELLO WORLD!";

let z = 16 * 11;
for (row = 0; row < 11; row++) {
  for (col = 0; col < 16; col++) {
    let tile = document.createElement("div");
    tile.style.zIndex = z--;
    
    container.appendChild(tile);
    $(tile).addClass("tile");
    
    if (row == 5 && col > 1 && col < 14) {
      let p = document.createElement("p");
      
      tile.appendChild(p);
      $(p).addClass("letter");
      $(p).text(string[col - 2]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  --tileWidth: 30px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth) var(--tileWidth);
}

.tile {
  display: block;
  width: var(--tileWidth);
  height: var(--tileWidth);
  position: relative;
  background-color: teal;
  font-size: calc(var(--tileWidth)*2);
  color: tomato;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Impact;
}

.letter {
  overflow: visible visible;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Super.  The z-index method works well.  I plan on animating theses elements, so my guess is that adding the divs in reverse order will create overlaps in the reverse direction if they move.  I tried adding a z-index to the letter class, but that didn't change the output.  I thought all of the p's would be drawn in front of all of the div's, and the p's have no background colors.  Does each element create a new z-index framework for its child elements?

Comment: It turns out my earlier experiments with z-index didn't work because z is disabled by default.  An element's position property has to be changed to anything other than default in order for the elements z-value to be used in drawing it.  I'm still not clear on why z-index doesn't work on p's, since the doc's say the position property applies to all elements.  Here I nested the letters within a second div with no background color, relative position, and a z-index, and the letters overflow:  https://codepen.io/fcdobbs/pen/mdGbYgB?editors=0100